# How to have every state transition to a single state when a trigger occurs using Stateless?

Tags: c#, state-machine, stateless-state-machine

I am using [stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) and have the following states:

- Foo
- Bar
- Faulted

When the fault trigger happens, I want the state machine to transition to the Faulted state, regardless of the previous state. Is there a way to do that something like:

```
machine.RegisterGlobalTrigger(Trigger.Fault, State.Faulted)
```

Note: I have thought of the following options, but looking for a "cleaner" solution:

1. Registering that trigger with every state
2. Creating an "Every" parent state that every class is a subclass of and registering the trigger there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't as pretty as the one-liner, but you could use a List of all possible states as a way of setting global or semi-global configuration, like:

```
Enum.GetValues<State>()
        .Where(state => state != State.Faulted) // so we don't put a Faulted .Permit() on the Faulted State
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(state =>
        {
            stateMachine.Configure(state)
                .Permit(Trigger.Fault, State.Faulted);
        });
```

Example with testing in this [dotnet fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/prdwhR).

Full example code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Stateless;

public class Program
{
    public enum State
    {
        Foo,
        Bar,
        Faulted
    }

    public enum Trigger
    {
        Fooify,
        Barify,
        Fault
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // setup
        var stateMachine = new StateMachine<State, Trigger>(State.Faulted);

        stateMachine.Configure(State.Foo)
            .Permit(Trigger.Barify, State.Bar);

        stateMachine.Configure(State.Bar)
            .Permit(Trigger.Fooify, State.Foo);

        stateMachine.Configure(State.Faulted)
            .Permit(Trigger.Fooify, State.Foo)
            .Permit(Trigger.Barify, State.Bar);

        Enum.GetValues<State>()
            .Where(state => state != State.Faulted) // so we don't put a Faulted .Permit() on the Faulted State
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(state =>
            {
                stateMachine.Configure(state)
                    .Permit(Trigger.Fault, State.Faulted);
            });

        // using the same pattern to add transition logging to every state
        Enum.GetValues<State>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(state =>
            {
                stateMachine.Configure(state)
                    .OnEntry(t => Console.WriteLine($"Entering {t.Destination} from {t.Source}"));
            });

        // testing
        // To Foo, then to Faulted
        stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Fooify);
        stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Fault);

        // To Bar, then to Faulted
        stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Barify);
        stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Fault);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea and implementation. Almost worth creating an extension method using that logic.